# How to view all sheet labels in MS excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, label

I have a MS excel file with many sheets and I need to move to them.

How can I list all the labels and move to a specific one?

Comment: On the bottom where all the sheet names are, there's also a button for left and right. Isn't that sufficient to scroll through the available sheets?

Comment: Or, right click on area @LPChip has pointed out.

Comment: @LPChip is not useful because I have many sheets with very long names

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I've just written three macros which will do this reasonably well. The first macro generates a summary sheet (named **sh_summary**) at the end of your workbook, and selects it. Then, from this new summary sheet, you select one of the sheet names that you want (e.g. select cell A2), and then launch the second macro which will select/navigate to the sheet you chose. The third macro will take you back to the summary sheet. The 2nd + 3rd macros should be shortcutted, for fast navigation.

1:

```
Sub findSheets()
    Dim sheetNum As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim theSh(999)

    'count sheets:
    sheetNum = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    'check for a summary sheet and delete it if found:
    For i = 1 To sheetNum
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name = "sh_summary" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i

    'count sheets again:
    sheetNum = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    'get sheet names
    For i = 1 To sheetNum
        theSh(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
    Next i

    'create summary sheet:
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "sh_summary"

    'print sheet names on summary sheet:
    For i = 1 To sheetNum
        Cells(1, 1).Value = "Worksheet summary:"
        Cells((1 + i), 1).Value = theSh(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

2:

```
Sub navToSheet()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveCell.Value).Select
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't find sheet - select and try again."
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

3:

```
Sub navToSummary()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sh_summary").Select
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't find summary sheet."
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```